# ?define macro or .hrl file alternate in Elixir for configuration purpose

Tags: constants, elixir

In Erlang I can use define macro or .hrl file to keep the configuration at one place. Whats the best place to do it in Elixir.

I couldn't find any elegant way of doing it. Right Now I am doing something like:-

```
def get_server_name do
    "TEST"
end
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you use functions or macros should matter too much in the end, but if what you're looking for is the "keeping it in one place" part, I'd suggest putting it in its own namespace/module

```
defmodule MyApp.Configuration
  def server_name do
    "foo"
  end

  # or if you prefer having it all on one line
  def host_name, do: "example.com"

  # for complete equivalency, you can use a macro
  defmacro other_config do
    "some value"
  end
end
```

and then in your app, instead of including the file, you can alias the module so have a short prefix to indicate it's configuration, and indicate they come from elsewhere

```
defmodule MyApp.Server do
  alias MyApp.Configuration, as: C
end
```

or if you want to use the names directly

```
defmodule MyApp.Server do
  import MyApp.Configuration
end
```

Comment: Perfect answer! The exact equivalent to Erlang .hrl file would be exactly this solution but using `defmacro` to define each configuration, guaranteeing they are replaced at compilation time (as in Erlang macros).

Comment: Thanks Carlos and Jose, This is how I am doing at present, Except not creating alias :). Elixir has module level custom attribute, How about instead of using functions using those?

Comment: That would only be available inside the one module, which would be quire a different use-case from defining a compile-time shared configuration as described.

Comment: Hmm.. yaa you are right. I was thinking using import we can access the attributes in other module which can act as a configuration file in that case.

Comment: The attributes are not shared via import. In fact, unless the attribute is persisted, they completely disappear once you compile the module. You could definitely inject the attributes using macros but that would be confusing imo.

Comment: @JoséValim: Yaa, BTW how can I persist attribute?

Comment: Check out Module.register_attribute/3 for persisting an attribute.